# Send an audio buffer to the client to download without storing in the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a text-to-speech service with the help of IBM Watson API. Using the following code segment I was able to download the converted .wav file to my server.

```
textToSpeech
    .synthesize(synthesizeParams)
    .then((response) => {
      return textToSpeech.repairWavHeaderStream(response.result)
    })
    .then((buffer) => {
      fs.writeFileSync(buffer, 'hello_world.wav')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error:', err)
    })
```

But I do not want to store audio files whenever a text has been converted. How can I send the buffer directly to the users to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach could be to set-up an endpoint that takes the text to be converted to speech that calls the IBM Wastson api and within `then` have the `buffer` be sent directly to the user on the `res` object. (I see you tagged express-js)

Take a look at these two articles and this YT video (on streaming video) for suggestions/artifacts on how to approach,

- [streaming audio 1](https://medium.com/@richard534/uploading-streaming-audio-using-nodejs-express-mongodb-gridfs-b031a0bcb20f)
- [streaming audio 2](https://apiko.com/blog/audio-file-streaming-in-js/)
- [stream video to use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjBLbXUuyWg)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. res.send (buffer) was the solution